# Bootstrapper for MEF CompositionContainer in WCF website

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, mef

I need to run a `Bootstrapper / Init` method to populate a `MEF` `CompositionContainer` in a website that hosts my `WCF` services.  The website is hosted in `IIS` and only holds 2 `.svc` files that point to the service implementation in a different project.  I don't want to make this website any bigger than it has to be.  The `Init` method I want to run is shown below:

```
public static CompositionContainer Init()
{
    AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
    catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(PlayerRepository).Assembly));
    CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

    return container;
}
```

Can this be done through the `Web.config`?  Or is there a class I can add to the website that could perform this task.  I can do this easy enough if I host the services in a `Windows` Service as I can call this in the `On_Start()`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a Global.asax and calling my Init() method from the Application_Start().  This means only 1 extra file in the website.